# How to make a conversion from std::string_view to std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++17, implicit-conversion, string-view

How is it possible that this code below with conversion from `std::string_view` to `std::string` compiles:

```cpp
struct S {
    std::string str;
    S(std::string_view str_view) : str{ str_view } { }
};
```

but this one does not compile?

```cpp
void foo(std::string) { }
int main() {
    std::string_view str_view{ "text" };
    foo(str_view);
}
```

The second one gives an error: `cannot convert argument 1 from std::string_view to std::string` and `no sutiable user-defined conversion from std::string_view to std::string exists`.

How should I call `foo()` properly?

Comment: What is the error(s) you get from the second example? Please copy-paste them in full and complete (and as text) into your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The constrcutor you are trying to call is

```
// C++11-17
template< class T >
explicit basic_string( const T& t,
                       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

// C++20+                                          
template< class T >
explicit constexpr basic_string( const T& t,
                                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and as you can see, it is marked as `explicit`, meaning no implicit conversion is allowed to call that constructor.

With `str{ str_view }` you are explicitly initializing the string with the string view, so it is allowed.

With `foo(str_view)` you are relying on the compiler to implicitly convert the `string_view` into a `string`, and because of the explicit constructor you will get a compiler error.  To fix it you need to be explicit like
`foo(std::string{str_view});`

Answer (score 2):

> How should I call foo() properly?

Like this:

```
foo(std::string{str_view});
```

---

> How is it possible that this code below with conversion from std::string_view to std::string compiles:

It is an explicit conversion to `std::string`. It can invoke the explicit converting constructor.

> but this one does not compile?

It is an implicit conversion to `std::string`. It cannot invoke the explicit converting constructor.